# How to remove the null values from the json input

Tags: javascript, json, null

how to remove the property that contains null value from the below input

```
var data = [
        { "Id": "parent", "Function": "Project Management", "Phase": "(Null)" },
        { "Id": "1", "Function": "R&D Team", "Phase": "parent" },
        { "Id": "2", "Function": "HR Team", "Phase": "parent" },
        { "Id": "3", "Function": "Sales Team", "Phase": "parent" },
        { "Id": "4", "Function": "Philosophy", "Phase": "1" },
        { "Id": "5", "Function": " Organization", "Phase": "1" },

     ];
```

Comment: Unclear: What exactly need to remove? Property/Object? Showing no efforts.

Comment: need to remove the property that contains null value

Comment: [edit] the question and add the code you've tried to solve this problem.

Comment: What if `{ "Id": "parent", "Function": "Project Management", "Phase": "" }` or `{ "Id": "parent", "Function": "Project Management", "Phase": null}`?

Comment: @Mamun   

`{ "Id": "parent", "Function": "Project Management", "Phase": "" } or { "Id": "parent", "Function": "Project Management", "Phase": null} `

For this case i have no issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
data = data.map(obj => Object.keys(obj).reduce((prev, prop) => {
  // you can check for '(Null)', null or for any different kind of value here
  if (obj[prop] != '(Null)') {
    prev[prop] = obj[prop]
  }
  return prev
}, {}))
```

Comment: Also You can do as  : 
`data.forEach((d, v)=> { for(x in d) {

    if(d[x] == "(Null)") {  delete d[x] }; 
 }});`